# unset array items at once which has same words and send those to another array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to unset a couple items from an array at once, send unsetted items to another array.

```
array(6) {
    [0]=> string(65) "https://www.kintetsu-re.co.jp/mansion_kansai/outline/midosuji241/"
    [1]=> string(41) "https://geo.8984.jp/outline/suminodo.html"
    [2]=> string(56) "http://www.sohgoh-outline.jp/index.php?bunjo_number=0141"
    [3]=> string(56) "http://www.sohgoh-outline.jp/index.php?bunjo_number=0136"
    [4]=> string(56) "http://www.sohgoh-outline.jp/index.php?bunjo_number=0099"
    [5]=> string(53) "https://www.sgr-sumai.jp/mansion/tezukayama21/outline"
}
```

Three links in this array starts with http://www.sohgoh-outline.jp . So I'm trying to unset those. But not one by one. I can already doing it. For example, I tried to locate those with `strpos`

```
$needle = "http://www.sohgoh-outline.jp/";

foreach ($link as $unset){
    if (($index = strpos($unset, $needle)) !== false){
        $renai [] = $unset[$index];
        unset($unset[$index]);
    }
}
```

But this error popping up.

> Cannot unset string offsets

Any suggestions?

Comment: `unset($link[$index]);` instead of `unset($unset[$index]);` $unset is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code like this:

```
foreach ($link as $k => $unset){
    if ((strpos($unset, $needle)) !== false)
    {
        $renai [] = $link[$k]; // This will add the value to new array.
        unset($link[$k]);  // THIS WILL UNSET THE VALUE.
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, it solved the problem. But I didn't understand the value part. Because array items doesn't have the value... ? how did it worked? could you explain it a bit please. By the a couple min late I will check this as answer.

Comment: I did not understand your query with `'But I didn't understand the value part.'`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is probably regex with preg_grep and array_diff.

```
$out = preg_grep("/.*?(sohgoh-outline\.jp).*/", $arr);

var_dump($out); //sohgoh-outline.jp links

$arr = array_diff($arr, $out);
var_dump($arr); // all but sohgoh-outline.jp links
```

Output of above code:

```
array(3) {
  [2]=>
  string(56) "http://www.sohgoh-outline.jp/index.php?bunjo_number=0141"
  [3]=>
  string(56) "http://www.sohgoh-outline.jp/index.php?bunjo_number=0136"
  [4]=>
  string(56) "http://www.sohgoh-outline.jp/index.php?bunjo_number=0099"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(65) "https://www.kintetsu-re.co.jp/mansion_kansai/outline/midosuji241/"
  [1]=>
  string(41) "https://geo.8984.jp/outline/suminodo.html"
  [5]=>
  string(53) "https://www.sgr-sumai.jp/mansion/tezukayama21/outline"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/Um46H

Comment: Thank your for the another approuch! This looks much more simple.

Comment: @NigelRen really? I thought you knew regex. It's really handy.

Comment: There is a difference between getting by and knowing something well enough to use it with confidence.  Also the trade off of performance and being maintainable is always a concern I have.  But that will be something I can experiment with.

Comment: True. But performance is most of the times not something to worry about. Sure it will impact but a well written regex that removes loops and a ton of ifs is better in my opinion even if the cost is a few microseconds. It's usually far easier to debug a regex than loops and ifs.